# "Sparsity" vs "sparseness"

Tags: differences, nouns

What is the difference between *sparsity* and *sparseness*? Is it that the latter emphasises the extent to which something is sparse? I'm not sure I can see the thin line that separates them.

Answer (score 6):

I think you will be hard-pressed to find any true, measureable, or generally-accepted distinction between these two words. Even in the most technical literature the distinction is extremely subtle. For example, in [this paper](http://ojs.academypublisher.com/index.php/jcp/article/view/02066571) I *believe* the author is using "sparsity" as a quality or a characteristic of a set (in the boolean sense: either it *has it* or it *doesn't*), and "sparseness" as a metric (referring to the "degree of", or "the measure of" sparseness). But even there I think it's a stretch; the words seem to be interchangeable.

Personally, I rarely hear the word "sparsity" used (and only in very technical contexts), "sparseness" being preferred. However, even that distinction [doesn't appear to be supported in the literature](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sparsity%2Csparseness&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Having said all that, I should point out that in spoken English, neither word is commonly used outside of technical jargon.
(Note the relative **sparseness** of both of the words [relative to the word "sparse"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sparsity%2Csparseness%2C+sparse&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), for example.) In practice, I would recommend maintaining a **sparcity** of usage of the words. :)